# Sort html table alphabetically on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm looking to sort a html table alphabetically on page load the same way you can sort an unordered list.

I tried to use the code below but did not work:

```
    var mylist = $('#myTable');
var listitems = mylist.children('tr').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

And then

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td>12/01/2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>12/01/2016</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want it to sort the table alphabetically by the first column in a row.

I can't find anything about this online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this line did not return your trs:

```
var listitems = mylist.children('tr').get();
```

Modify to below and everything will work.

```
var listitems = mylist.find('tr');
```

```js
var mylist = $('#myTable');
var listitems = mylist.find('tr');
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td>12/01/2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>12/01/2016</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you did not inject jquery into your jsfiddle

Comment: @ShaneBuckley you should type jquery url in exteral resources.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that I use. note: This is faster than using jquery find()

```js
function sortTable(){
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var Arr = [];
    for(var i=0, ln=table.rows.length; i<ln; i++){
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var firstCell = row.cells[0].textContent;
     Arr.push([firstCell, row]);  //temporary array
    }
//sort by first column of inner arrays
    Arr = Arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a[0] > b[0];
});
    for(var i=0, ln=Arr.length; i<ln; i++){
        table.appendChild(Arr[i][1]);
    }
    Arr = null;
}
sortTable();
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>d</td>
<td>12/03/2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td>12/01/2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>12/04/2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td>12/04/2016</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is better, But i don't want to sort <th>.. this is sorting entire table... Kindly please help...

Comment: @AbijithAjayan Could you explain this a bit clearly. I did not get what you mean by sorting entire table and dont want to sort <th>.

Comment: Actually in my table.. Inside one <tr> Tag Four <td> Tag is there...Like this so many <tr> tags are there... its coming like vertically.. First <Td> and Third <Td> is the Name and the second <Td> and fourth <Td> is place... based on the persons birth place.... I want to sort by persons name..  based on persons name place will also sort.. I tried... But, while sorting.. Its considering First <TD> and based on this first <td> temaining every <td> is sorting.. That is the problem.. I want main sort function in first<td> and third<td>

Comment: @tkayI want like this,  Based on first<td> second <td> has to be sort and based on the third<td> fourth <td>  has to be sort... Actually am getting, for only first<td> evry <td> is going has this child.